# Cannot download a particular file from the website

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I need download generated csv file at the following address:

http://www.mbank.pl/bin/sfi/sfi_do_csv.php?sh=0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11&date=2013-04-05&sorted=StopaZw1r_down&fund_type=&collection=&show=all

Unfortunately, in most cases, the timeout occurs despite the fact that when you type a web address in your browser starts downloading the file correctly.

I tried all the ways I know. My current code:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.mbank.pl/bin/sfi/sfi_do_csv.php?sh=0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11&date=2013-04-05&sorted=StopaZw1r_down&fund_type=&collection=&show=all", @"d:\myfile.csv");
```

Please help and modify the code so that the file would download properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "CustomClient");
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.mbank.pl/bin/sfi/sfi_do_csv.php?sh=0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11&date=2013-04-05&sorted=StopaZw1r_down&fund_type=&collection=&show=all", @"d:\myfile.csv");
```

Some servers refuse to answer if you don't specify your "user agent". I have no idea why this is so, but here.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Your help solve the problem. Misled me that a few hours ago to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.mbank.pl/bin/sfi/sfi_do_csv.php?sh=0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11&date=2013-04-05&sorted=StopaZw1r_down&fund_type=&collection=&show=all",  @"D:\Downloads\1.zip");
  }
```

OR IF ANY EXCEPTION IS THERE TRY THIS

```
public void DownloadFile(string _URL, string _SaveAs)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebClient _WebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            // Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file.
            _WebClient.DownloadFile(_URL, _SaveAs);
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            // Error
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
        }
    }
```

OR TRY THIS WILL WORK

```
public class WebDownload : WebClient
{
    private int _timeout;
    /// <summary>
    /// Time in milliseconds
    /// </summary>
    public int Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeout;
        }
        set
        {
            _timeout = value;
        }
    }

    public WebDownload()
    {
        this._timeout = 60000;
    }

    public WebDownload(int timeout)
    {
        this._timeout = timeout;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var result = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        result.Timeout = this._timeout;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get connetion timeout.
The problem probably lies with the query. I guess I have to do with "POST". But not quite know how.

Comment: Try this WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(). You can call CancelAsync() by timer with your own timeout.